# Isometry in the dual of $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, lp-spaces, duality-theorems

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of different points in $C[0,1]$ and let $y=(y_1,...)\in l_1$.
Define $f_y:C[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $f_y(\phi)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\phi(a_n)$.

How do I show that

> 1. the map $h:l_1\rightarrow (C[0,1])^{'}$ with $h(y)=f_y$ is an isometric map?
> 2. $h(l_1)$ is a closed subspace of $(C[0,1])^{'}$
> 3. $C[0,1]$ is not reflexive?

What I thought:
1. To be an isometry, we must have $||h(y)||=||y||$ for all $||y||\in l_1$.
We know that $||h(y)||=||f_y||=\sup\{||f_y(\phi)||:||\phi||\leq1\}$, where $||f_y(\phi)||\leq||y||\cdot||\phi||$ since $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n\phi(a_n)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n|\cdot ||\phi||=||y||\cdot||\phi||$.
All we have to do is prove that $||f_y(\phi)||\geq||y||\cdot||\phi||$. How do we do that?

2. Let $(f_{y^1},f_{y^2},...)$ be a converging sequence of elements in $h(l_1)$ s.t. $f_{y^n}\rightarrow F$. I think we need to show that $F\in h(l_1)$, which means that we want to show that there is a $y\in l_1$ such that $F=f_y$. I assume that this $y$ should be the limit of the $y^n$. How would I show this?
3. For $\phi\in C[0,1]$ let $e_\phi:(C[0,1])^{'}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $e_\phi(f)=f(\phi)$. Further let $J:C[0,1]\rightarrow(C[0,1])^{''}$ with $J(\phi)=e_\phi$.
   To be reflexive, we must have $J(C[0,1])=(C[0,1])^{''}$. What is an element of $(C[0,1])^{''}$ that is not in $J(C[0,1])$?

Edit:
2 Following LeBtz's hint we get:
Let $(f_{y^1},f_{y^2},...)$ be a Cauchy sequence of elements in $h(l_1)$ with pre-images $y^1,y^2n,..$ in $l_1$. Then we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n,m\geq N$ we have
$$||f_{y^n}-f_{y^m}||<\epsilon.$$
Since $h$ is an isometry it follows that $||y^n-y^m||=||f_{y^n}-f_{y^m}||<\epsilon$, so $\{y^n\}$ is Cauchy in $l_1$ and thus converges to a $y\in l_1$. Thus there exists an $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$ we get 
$$||f_{y}-f_{y^n}||=||y-y^n||<\epsilon.$$
So $\{f_{y^n}\}$ converges to $f_y$, which is in $l_1$.

Comment: Your edit is correct. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is $N\in\mathbb N$ with $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |y_n|<\epsilon$. Now the collection $\{a_1,...,a_N\}$ is finite so we can find a continuous function $\phi:[0,1]\to \mathbb C$ with $\phi(a_i) = \overline{\operatorname{sgn}(y_i)}$ if $i\leq N$ and $\|\phi\|_\infty\leq 1$. <sup>1</sup>
Now $$|f_y(\phi)| = \left|\sum_{n=1}^N |y_i| + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty y_n\phi(a_n)\right| \geq  \sum_{n=1}^N|y_i|-\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |y_n|\underbrace{|\phi(a_n)|}_{<1} >\|y\|-2\epsilon.$$ Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary this yields the first claim.

2) Images of complete spaces with respect to an isometry are complete and hence closed. Take a cauchy sequence in $h(\ell^1)$, show that its preimages are Cauchy aswell and therefore must converge in $\ell^1$ and conclode that the sequence must converge in $h(\ell^1)$ due to continuity of $h$.

3) Every closed subspace of a relfexive space is itself reflexive. $\ell^1$ is not reflexive.

<sup>1</sup> We can define $\phi$ on the finite set $\{a_1,...,a_N\}$ and then interpolate linearly for example.

Comment: For 3, I assume you mean that since $h(l^1)$ is closed but not reflexive, $C[0,1]$ cannot be reflexive. However, why is $h(l^1)$ not reflexive if $l^1$ is not?

Comment: @EdMalone Since $h(\ell^1)$ is an isometric image of $\ell^1$, every property that $\ell^1$ has as a normed space is preserved. It is literally the same space just with other names for the elements. If you want a formal proof, look at the isometric isomorphism $h:\ell^1\to h(\ell^1)$. Then $h''$ is an isometric isomorphism aswell. If the embedding $\iota:h(\ell^1)\to h(\ell^1)''$ was an isomorphism than so is $(h'')^{-1}\circ \iota\circ h$ but this is exactly the canonical embedding $\ell^1\to(\ell^1)''$

Comment: Could you please expand your explanation for 2) a bit?

Comment: Don't you want to think a littlebit for youself on this one with the hints given?

Comment: I'll try to and let you know how it goes

Comment: Could you take a look at my edit?

Comment: What is the function $\overline{\text{sgn}(y_i)}$ exactly?

Comment: $\operatorname{sgn}(z)$ returns $\frac{z}{|z|}$ if $z\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. It is a generalization of the real signum-function and has the property that $z = |z|\operatorname{sgn}(z)$. On the other hand we always have $|z| = z\cdot\overline{\operatorname{sgn}(z)}$

Comment: But what is the overline for?

Comment: Complex conjugation.

Comment: How does it follow that the $\phi$ defined is continuous?

Comment: @EdMalone We only define it on a finite set and interpolate linearly in between. I just edited that part a little bit to make it more clear.